# How to print only folder names where same name of file exists

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am trying to write a script where all matching file names exist. 
For example, I have a file TEST123 in many subfolders under /opt . I have a list of file names. So, I need to print only folder names which has the same file name .

Desired output :

```
TEST123
/opt/test2
/opt/test3
```

I am not sure how to use grep command :
I have a list "elements.txt" with full path of file names. And I cutted only the filenames at the end to " onlyfile.txt" .

This is how elements.txt look with many different file names, some of them has duplicated and some dont.

```
/opt/test2/TEST123
/opt/test3/TEST123
/opt/test2/TEST577
/opt/test6/SUNNY
/opt/test8/SUNNY
```

This is onlyfile.txt:

```
TEST123
TEST577
SUNNY
and many more files
```

And need to loop with the filename , like

```
for item in `cat onlyfile.txt`
 do
  grep elements.txt
 done
```

It is giving me all outputs, but I  need only folder names .
Any help would be appreciated.!

Comment: Thank you for reply. I edited how files look inside

Comment: iF i understand you correctly, you have a list of relative pathes and want to know which of them denote plain files below /opt, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

To get the directory of every file named `TEST123`, use the `find` command:

```
find /opt -name TEST123 -printf "%h\n"
```

The output will be:

```
/opt/test2
/opt/test3
```

The `%h` specifier will output the directory of the file. See the [`find` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/findutils/find.1.en.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i think you need more than one loop.

```
for item in `cat onlyfile.txt`; do
    for path in `cat elements.txt |grep $item`; do
            dirname $path
    done
done
```

First loop iterate filenames

Second loop searches filenames in paths and strip file name from them